# Boolean Operation is not filling mesh

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to make a cutout like the following (a hourglass shape) in an object.
But when I add the boolean it doesn't fill the mesh. I get a cut out like a cylinder instead.
You can see the inside of the object.

There is only a subdivision modifier on the object applied currently.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your boolean below your subdivision mod in the stack? Also, can you clarify what you mean by fill the mesh?

Comment: Boolean operations tend to "glitch out" if your meshes are non-magnifold. Fill in the caps of you hourglass mesh and try again. Also, make sure there are no faces in the middle of the hourglass mesh.

Comment: @Michael I"ve updated the post with a photo so you can see where the gap is, you can see inside the shape

Comment: @metaphor_set I've tried it but with no result, i even tried a normal cylinder but got the same result..

Comment: Have you made sure that all your normals are facing the correct direction? Go into edit mode select everything and hit Shitft+N to recalculate. Also, make sure that you don't have any vertices/edges/faces that share the exact same position with the part to be cut.

Answer (score -1):

I've found the problem, it had to do with the Mirror modifier. When I created the object I deleted 1 face of the object that was on the inside. Which is why it was empty instead of filling.